# How to set sync interval of 15 minutes for sync adapter.?

Tags: java, android

Below is the updated code

```
public class MainActivityNew extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private static final String Tag = "MainActivity";
    // Instance fields
    Account mAccount;

    public static final long SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60L;
    public static final long SYNC_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES = 15L;
    public static final long SYNC_INTERVAL =
            SYNC_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES *
                    SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_EX = 1;

    ContentResolver resolver;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Create the dummy account
        mAccount = CreateSyncAccount(this);
        resolver = getContentResolver();
        resolver.setIsSyncable(mAccount, CommonUtilities.AUTHORITY, 1);
        resolver.setSyncAutomatically(mAccount, CommonUtilities.AUTHORITY, true);
        resolver.addPeriodicSync(
                mAccount,
                CommonUtilities.AUTHORITY,
                Bundle.EMPTY,
                SYNC_INTERVAL);}

    public static Account CreateSyncAccount(Context context) {
        // Create the mAccount call_type and default mAccount
        Account newAccount = new Account(
                ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        // Get an instance of the Android mAccount manager
        AccountManager accountManager =
                (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(
                        ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
        /*
         * Add the mAccount and mAccount call_type, no password or user data
         * If successful, return the Account object, otherwise report an error.
         */
        if (accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, null, null)) {
            /*
             * If you don't set android:syncable="true" in
             * in your <provider> element in the manifest,
             * then call context.setIsSyncable(mAccount, AUTHORITY, 1)
             * here.
             */
            ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(newAccount, AUTHORITY, 1);
            ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(true);
            ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, AUTHORITY, true);
        } else {
            /*
             * The mAccount exists or some other error occurred. Log this, report it,
             * or handle it internally.
             */
            Log.d(Tag, "Error occured in creating mAccount");
        }
        return newAccount;
    }
```

and also I am sending sync interval time like 1*60*1000

1. How to set sync interval of 15 minutes for sync adapter ?
2. What is the difference between 1*60*1000L and 1*60*1000 ?

Answer (score 1):

1*60*1000 = 60 000 = 1 minute,

1. use 15*60*1000 to set your sync interval to 15 minutes.
2. 1*60*1000L returns a long where as 1*60*1000 returns an int(not good for large numbers)

Comment: `long SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60L;
long SYNC_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES = 15L;
long SYNC_INTERVAL =
            SYNC_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES *
            SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;`
Have a look at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html

Comment: Not working , it again syncing with time interval of 1 minute

Comment: Thats weird, could you please try using 900000L as your sync interval. Tested it now, and it works for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146030/discussion-between-archlucifer-and-matin-sayyad).